# Solving the 2D Wave Equation on a Polygon Membrane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polygons, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

Is it possible to solve the 2d wave equation on a Polygon membrane (such as a hexagon)? And if so, would separation of variables hold in this case?

Comment: Yes, everything can be solved numerically. No, you are not going to be able to separate the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your wisdom. I was hoping that I would obtain a nice, compact solution, but I guess I'll have to preceed with numerical analysis. I didn't know whether it would at all be possible to obtain a neat solution by symmetry arguments for a regular polygon.

Comment: This topic has been quite for a while, but maybe somebody can provide more insight? For example, one can solve the wave equation on a square and disc easily.